# DBeaver on OSX - null connection returned

Tags: java, macos, postgresql, dbeaver

I can't connect to a postgreSQL database with DBeaver on osx (latest) and get this cryptic `null connection returned`

I can however connect with teamSQL without a problem.

I checked a ton of resources but I have no idea of the cause of this problem so my connection infos are the right ones.

For information I have java installed :

```
java -version
java version "9.0.1"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 9.0.1+11)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 9.0.1+11, mixed mode)
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I'll provide a proper answer in case anyone runs into the same problem :

I am on osx and my team mates are on windows, we provided the same credentials but they were able to log in and I wasn't.

The problems comes from DBeaver on osx that will not strip the `http://` from the beginning of urls and will not accept `.com/:1244` as a valid port but will accept those without a problem on windows.

The correct way to input a url would then be `mywebsite.com:1244`

Hope that helps.

Comment: this resolved my issue. removing http: from the host URL.

Answer (score 2):

As with **DBeaver v6.1.2**
The issue is observed in windows as well, you need to manually strip off the "http:\" from the Host URL. Also mention the port explicitly in the Port text box.

Answer (score 0):

What version of DBeaver are you using? [4.2.3](https://dbeaver.jkiss.org/2017/10/15/dbeaver-4-2-3/) is the latest version that supports Java 9 (4.2.2 was the first, but there were a few issues).

Comment: Thanks for your time ! You pointed me to the logs (didn't know where they were) and it helped me resolve the problem, I had a `/` at the end of my url so the connection was ending in `.com/:1244` and same was for the start of it, I needed to strip the `http://`. My colleagues are on windows and didn't have to do that though and the same connection credentials were working on teamSQL too.